# Resize a SkinnablePopupContainer

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I an mobile application, I want to open a popup, and I want to resize it dynamically.
I am using a SkinnablePopupContainer and I open it with popup.open(view, true);
If I try to reduce the size with popup.width = ... the content of the popup overflows. If there a way to redraw the content of the container so it fits well ?

Thks

Comment: Could you add sample code?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use .validateNow() to redraw the content.

Comment: also, think about adding a maxWidth = popup's dynamic width before redrawing the component.